# Consuming Wcf from classic asp (with datacontract)

Tags: wcf, asp-classic, vbscript

I'm currently developing a WCF service (Service.svc) and I would like to consume it with classic ASP. Naturally, i first checked how to on Google and Mdsn Library. I managed to connect my service.

But here is the problem, i can call simple method like :

```
string GetData(int i)
```

But I have some DataContracts too a methods signed like this :

```
IsAvailRef[] AreAvailable(MyInType data)
```

\With IsAvailRef as DataContract and so is MyInType.
And when I call these methods, I've an Asp error  'ASP 0106 : 80020005' saying "A data type not supported has been detected."

So here is my question : **Can't we use DataContract with VB script ?**

This is the signature of my function in the library generated by regasm.exe like explained in this article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752245.aspx

```
[id(0x60020000)]
HRESULT AreReferencesAvailable([out, retval] SAFEARRAY(_IsAvailRef*)* pRetVal);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe DataContract is a class and is not a valid VBScript subtype:

http://www.csidata.com/custserv/onlinehelp/vbsdocs/vbs6.htm

You can probably call it's methods, however I doubt you can store it in a variant.